# Can't boot into Recovery mode. Prestigio Multipad 2 Pro Duo 7.0

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, boot, tablet, prestigio-multipad

so I've had the Prestigio Multipad 2 Pro Duo 7.0 for a hell of a long time. Sitting in a box, the tablet worked fine when we bought it back in like 2015 for like 2 - 3 weeks and then we started to run into problems like the booting won't start or it just freezes randomly. And to fix it we'd have to wipe all the data using Android Recovery. Until we couldn't get the Recovery menu to pop-up anymore, the Volume Up/Down + Power did absolutely nothing. And here I am 7 years later trying to recover it yet again. Right now the tablet hasn't changed at all, still got the same problem and all that time sitting in a box did not help it. I was thinking of flashing new firmware to it and stuff like that but I have no idea how to do so if the tablet won't start (stuck on boot screen). There's no way for windows to recognize it.
What I tried in the meantime while playing around with it:

Replugging the battery back in

Installed drivers for ADB(still doesn't recognize it)

Tried booting into Recovery with Volume + Power buttons(tried it in every single scenario and it wouldn't work)

(later i realized ADB only works if the device is on..)

Literally any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134782/discussion-on-question-by-tex-cant-boot-into-recovery-mode-prestigio-multipad).